# how to write code for 'Loading...Please wait' in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on a project related to database. On clicking the button, the code for data extraction gets executed..I wish to display 'Loading...Please Wait' till application do not display output on web page...so,how to do it in asp.net?

Comment: You need to show some code, let us know your efforts, show information about your environment and so on - otherwise the risk of getting that question closed is high.

Comment: you must use updatepanel and updateprogress

Comment: @Ali :okay, But where to place that code( updatepanel and updateprogress) in asp page?

Comment: refer to my answer below and find the link, it might help you

Answer (score 2):

please don't use updatepanel / nor include other libraries just for this simple task :

You can use ajax. ( js/jq)

when you submit ( not postback of course....)  , you show a div which has a gif or something " please wait while loading ...."

When the callback of the ajax response is back : you simply hide this div

that's all.

clean and simple .

Answer (score 1):

you can use asp.net ajax to solve this, using an updatepanel and updateprogress, refer to this article for more details:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386421(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: please don't ....this is such a simple task where including a library for it will be a crime. not to mention that upodatepanel is very old implementation and there are much better options

Answer (score 1):

You can use RadAjaxLoadingPanel.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel MinDisplayTime="1000" ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 600px;"
            IsSticky="True">
            <div class="overlay" id="divProgress" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; vertical-align: middle; border-style: inset; border-color: black; background-color: White; width: 200px; height: 100px; font-size: medium;">
                <center>
                <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
                    <asp:Image GenerateEmptyAlternateText="true" ID="imgLoader" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax_loading.gif"
                        Style="margin-top: 7px;" />  
                    <asp:Label ID="lblWait" runat="server" Text="Please wait..."></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </center>
            </div>
        </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [AjaxLoadingPanel](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/loadingpanel/loadingimages/defaultcs.aspx) in Telerik 
By this You can Get Very Rich UI

**Edited**

go for Jquery Loading

for Simple Code go to w3schools **[LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp)**

Comment: what You mean @RoyiNamir

Comment: @RoyiNamir Agreed +1 to your answer.